# I cannot sculpt grease pencil strokes or see the cursor(display cursor is on)

Tags: grease-pencil, sculpt-mode

A new project works good. but this specific project was from 2.9x, and now i opened in 3.6 but i cannot sculpt the strokes any of it. Even if i make a new grease pencil object(in this version or 2.9 it wont let me sculpt it ). is my file broken?

i resized the cursor with F but still goes back to invisible.

Answer (score 0):

i found it,

just once selected the brush in sculpt mode, go to the right on TOOL (active tool and workspace settings)
youll probably see the brush empty, if you click on the little arrow pointing down on the rightr, you can click RESET aLL brushes, or reset brush.  that worked for me. probably there was another way.  but this one worked.